# Exception calling a web service from another web service

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I need to call an axis2 web service inside another web service. Until now, I was doing it using a thread. I created a thread and invoked the web service and worked fine.

But, the thread is not really needed since I need to waik for the response anyway. So I've changed it and invoke it directly but it returns the following error

```
The server did not recognise the action which it received: 
    at es.cecabank.ealiapagos.servicios.wsimpl.operaciones.ws_operaciones_pagoconcargo.WS_operaciones_pagoConCargoSkeleton.realizarConciliacion(WS_operaciones_pagoConCargoSkeleton.java:471)
    at es.cecabank.ealiapagos.servicios.wsimpl.operaciones.ws_operaciones_pagoconcargo.WS_operaciones_pagoConCargoSkeleton.operacionesPagoConCargo(WS_operaciones_pagoConCargoSkeleton.java:174)
    at es.cecabank.ealiapagos.servicios.wsimpl.operaciones.ws_operaciones_pagoconcargo.WS_operaciones_pagoConCargoMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(WS_operaciones_pagoConCargoMessageReceiverInOut.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:488)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm struggling to see the cause of this. I see the action is set in the stub as always.

```
_operationClient.getOptions().setAction("op3215");
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

After studying the axis code, I've found the solution. Before actually executing the operation with _operationClient.execute(true); , I've changed a property in the message context.

```
_messageContext.setProperty(AddressingConstants.DISABLE_ADDRESSING_FOR_OUT_MESSAGES, true);
```

This way it works, for now. I don't know if it will have other implications.

As for the cause of the error, I think it has to do with the definition of the service I'm invoking. It doesn't have specific names for the input and the output actions:

```
<wsdl:operation name="op3215">
  <soap:operation soapAction="op3215"/>
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

instead of

```
  <wsdl:operation name="op3215">
     <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
     <wsdl:input name="op3215">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:input>
     <wsdl:output name="op3215">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
     </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
```

Then again, I'm not completely sure, and I don't know either why it worked fine using an independent thread.